# use cscope as semanticdb database back end in emacs

Tags: emacs, cscope, cedet

everone, I use cscope as semanticdb back end in emacs, it hints me that "Version of CScope is 15.5.  Need at least 16.0",but the newest version of CScope is 15.7a, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of CEDET are you using? I see in current bzr snapshot, and see that minimal required version is 15.7. The same is for 1.1 release. Maybe you need to upgrade to 1.1?

Comment: wel, my cedet version is 1.0.1, when I upgrade it to 1.1, I can't use the ecb,So I keep in the old version. my ecb version is 2.40 and cscope version is 15.7a. Can you give me more advices? Thanks alot.

Comment: well, this problem can be solved by changed the CSCOPE-MININUM-VERSION value, it does not matter anything.